# Google Chrome - Flash on Youtube issue

Tags: macos, google-chrome, adobe-flash, youtube

Here is the information about Flash plug-in in Google Chrome:

```
Flash - Version: 11.2.202.235
Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
```

It's able to load & stream videos on YouTube but the problem is, after about 10 seconds, the videos paused unexpectedly, even when it was buffered a lot more. When I tried to move the seeker to an other position, it continued to play but again, paused after 10 seconds.

The video which I've encountered errors:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3tedlWs1XY&feature=g-logo

Highly appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I think that's just part of Flash on OS X.  You could test the same YouTube videos in other browsers, as Chrome contains its own Flash rather than use the /Library plug-in version, but every YT video I've played on a Mac has always had that buffering pause a few seconds into it.  (Vimeo is usually smooth.)

There have been some sorta-hacks to set Mac browsers to use HTML5 instead of Flash, however: you might start with [Jon Gruber's always-excellent blog](http://daringfireball.net/2010/11/flash_free_and_cheating_with_google_chrome) though that may be somewhat outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You should try click 2 flash, a free extension for safari that puts a grey box in place of flash elements which aren't run until you left click them. The great part is that it detects youtube videos are runs them in a native video viewer (i'd say quicktime, but i'm not sure, might just be html 5) that's super smooth.